# How do you parse a literal asterisk with pyparsing?

Tags: python, grammar, pyparsing

I'm currently parsing a string, which can contain wildcards.
My grammar only works, if you put the asterisk in quotes.
How do you specify a literal *.

```
selection = QuotedString('"') | Word(printables) | Literal('*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any literal '*' is going to get sucked up into a `Word(printables)`.  Do you mean to have the word be made up of any printables that aren't asterisks? If so, then you can just change to:

```
selection = QuotedString('"') | Word(printables, excludeChars='*') | Literal('*')
```

Comment: I swapped the order around so that the literal was in the front which parsed correctly. Thanks for your answer, I'll definitely start using exclude chars :)